# Date Function for Access Query

Tags: datetime, ms-access

I am pulling data from 4 tables in a combination of 3 queries. All 3 queries contain one field that is common "PurchaseOrderNo", I also have a "DateUpdated" & "TimeUpdate" field I think I might be able to use for this issue.  The final query produces some filtered data and only the information needed. I am trying to figure out how to specify the query to only produce new data results since the query was last run, if that makes sense. this is my SQL, ignore the filters in place already.  Date format = MM/DD/YYYY Time format = ##.####

```
SELECT po_detail2.PurchaseOrderNo, po_detail2.VendorNo, po_detail2.ItemCode, po_detail2.LotSerialNo, IM068_MXPUnivProdCode.UDF_UNIQUE_KEY, Right([UDF_UNIQUE_KEY],1) AS SIZE_INDEX, Left([UDF_UNIQUE_KEY],Len([UDF_UNIQUE_KEY])-1) AS INVENTORY_KEY
FROM po_detail2 LEFT JOIN IM068_MXPUnivProdCode ON po_detail2.LotSerialNo = IM068_MXPUnivProdCode.LotSerialNo
WHERE (((po_detail2.PurchaseOrderNo)="0056334" Or (po_detail2.PurchaseOrderNo)>"0056334") AND ((po_detail2.ItemCode)="K500" Or (po_detail2.ItemCode)="PC55"))
ORDER BY po_detail2.PurchaseOrderNo DESC;
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but I suggest you use a parameterized querydef, Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao) BTW, What data types are DataUpdated and TimeUpdate? If DateUpdated is a date/time field then Time Updated is redundant.

Comment: What determines when query was last run? Are queries used as sources for reports? Do you have a VBA procedure that opens query/form/report and then updates a date/time field? How would new records be identified - if date field is Null?

Comment: @NicholasHunter DateUpdated is a Date/Time field and the TimeUpdated field is a short text field. reading up on link now.

Comment: @June7 I plan on running the query at 2-4 designated times in a day.  The query will be used to produce a csv file dropped on an ftp server.  Not proficient in VBA yet, so I have a task scheduler procedure set to run to open and run the query.  Each new record will have a unique identifier (PurchaseOrderNo).  I know I have others things to figure out down the road, just trying to take one step at a time.

Comment: Still doesn't explain how 'new' records can be identified. When you 'eyeball' the data, how would you identify which records are 'new' since last time table was run? Do you save the maximum PurchaseOrderNo at time of running into another table so next time only records with PON greater will be retrieved? Or is there a field for "DateRun" that  is only populated at time of running so in 'new' records this field will be Null? I expect whatever you do, VBA is going to be needed. So instead of TaskScheduler just running query, it needs to run a script that calls VBA procedure. I use VBScript file.

Comment: @June77  I would have to go by the most recent TimeUpdated value along with today's date.  "DateRun" field, are you referring to a field in a table or the query?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a qry that would send a timestamp to a table then filtering the results since the last qry was run. This is my qry SQL.

```
INSERT INTO tblQueryLastRun ( dtmQueryLastRun )
VALUES (Now());
```